# Pause HTML5 Video inside every iframe on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, html5-video

I have a page with multiple iframes containing one or more html5 videos. I'm trying to get all iframes on the page, get all videos inside each iframe and pause them. I always get a error with this approach for only one video. Thanks alot for your help!

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    var video = $(this).contents().find('video').first();
    video.get(0).pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with this code:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
        for (var i = 0; i< frames.length; i++) {
            var innerDoc = (frames.item(i).contentDocument) ? 
                frames.item(i).contentDocument : frames.item(i).contentWindow.document;
            var iframeVideoTags = innerDoc.getElementsByTagName("video");
            for (var j = 0; j < iframeVideoTags.length; j++) {
                iframeVideoTags.item(j).pause();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! What exactly do the "?" and ":" mean where you assign the values to innerDoc? Thank your for your time & help!

Comment: It is inline if: http://goo.gl/jRvYRm  and  http://goo.gl/Zc6Dkw  and  http://goo.gl/Xmsoid